# Class Function not existing in current context

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a class inside my main that calculates the amount of Carprofen an animal need with a given formula. I cant get the right syntax to make the method call, is this because its from another class?

I am trying to use

`Console.WriteLine($"\nYour pet requires {Carprofen(pet1)}ml of carprofen.");`

**Says that class Carprofen does not exist.**

here is my Pet Class:

```
public double Carprofen(Pet pet1) //The function
{
    if (pet1.Type == "Dog")
    {
        double dosage = ((pet1.Weight / 2.205) * (12 / 0.5));
        return (dosage);
    }
    else
    {
        double dosage = ((pet1.Weight / 2.205) * (12 / 0.25));
        return (dosage);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show a [example].

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear.  I can't tell for sure in what language is your sample, although I'll guess C#.  Your error message is that class Carprofen doesn't exist, but then you write _here's my Pet Class_.  So you have to be clear about what is a class and what is a function/method.

Comment: I'd also make several comments about style, such as factorising your code, but let's get the answer to your question first.  I'll leave that to a C# expert (assuming it _is_ C#).

Answer (score 0):

Use the name of the class then the method. If your class is in the different namespace, you have to provide the full path as well... namespace.class.method. also, you have to ensure both class and method are set up public if accessing outside your project

```
public class MyMethods{
  public double Carporfen...
...
}
```

You would call it in any other class like below. Make sure to use toString to convert double to string for console display

```
Console.WriteLine($"{MyMethods.Carporfen(pet1).ToString()}ml");
```

Comment: @rye does this answer your question?